# How to use cursor.executemany for other operations than insertion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
c = conn.cursor()
l=[(A,B,C),]
c.executemany("SELECT * FROM 'my_table' WHERE code=? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date",l) 
r = c.fetchall()
```

how can I make it work ? Is there any other alternatives ?

Comment: I think you can just use `execute` for `SELECT`.

Comment: We need example database data to test with.  What is the expected and current behavior?

Comment: well for exemple when you take the library website you have this :

purchases = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
             ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
             ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
            ]
c.executemany('INSERT INTO stocks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', purchases)

how can it be adapted to a selection with multiple ?

Answer (score 0):

```
c = conn.cursor()
l = (A, B, C)
c.execute("SELECT * FROM 'my_table' WHERE code=? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY date", l)
r = c.fetchall()
```